# Find the Side length of the shaded isosceles triangle

Tags: triangles, area

[Picture of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qujSF.gif)

How would one go about solving this problem? The question is asking you to find the length of X in the picture. The only thing they give us is the area of the shaded region, which is 3003cm^2. I've tried finding multiple solutions to this problem and can't find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area is the summation of the area of triangle and rectangle which is: $$\frac{x^2}{2}+x=3003\to x=\sqrt{6007}-1$$

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, where does  that -1 come from? I know that the model shows the 1cm, but how does that play into the problem?

Comment: The area of triangle is $\frac{x^2}{2}$ and that of rectangle is $x$. Both are with unit Cm^2. then we have $\frac{x^2}{2}+x=3003$ or $x^2+2x=6006$ or $x^2+2x+1=6007$ which leads to $(x+1)^2=6007$ and $x=\sqrt 6007-1$

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a trapezium and the larger base is $x$. The area of the trapezium is:
$$S=\frac{x+1}{2}\cdot x=3003 \Rightarrow x=77.$$